# Firefox and D3: Zoom + Pan bug

Tags: rendering, d3, firefox

I have a simple code [here](http://saludcorrientes.gob.ar/temp/bug/deptos_02.html) some map with zoom+pan effect. It work fine on Opera, Chrome even IE. But Firefox do not show it.-

If you open "Inspector" panel, you'll see has same values (translation, scale, path, d**) on Firefox than the other, but don't render properly.

Obviously is Firefox's bug cause on other browser works nice and D3 generate the code correctly.-

And [here](http://saludcorrientes.gob.ar/temp/bug/deptos_01.html) same map without zoom+pan effects, Firefox show it nice. Some google do not gave me any reference, console operation give the right value.

Any idea what's going wrong?

Here an snapshot. Can you see path.county's size?

### [image]

(*) code take it from Mike's site: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5914438
He use:

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .scale((1 << 12) / 2 / Math.PI)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

and 

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scale(projection.scale() * 2 * Math.PI)
    .scaleExtent([1 << 11, 1 << 14])
    .translate([width - center[0], height - center[1]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);
```

---

(**)

```
<svg width="600px" height="500px" transform="translate(5579.288888888889,-2536.2020481280824)scale(32768)"><path class="county" d="M239.07661387245844,54.......
```

Answer (score 1):

If I change the zoom variable to the following, it works also in Firefox:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function() {
        dptos.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    });
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @nipro, thank for help. But, same problem. I've added a screenshot to guidance.-

Comment: I have prepared a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpxgrLqh/). It works also with Firefox.

Comment: Yeap, its works in Firefox. But I need to limit zoom behavior. I think is a bug with .scaleExtent() in Firefox. Maybe there is a conflict with zoom function, maybe D3 override Firefox's function.

Comment: What about using two values in the array of .scaleExtent?

`var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 10]).on("zoom", function() {
        dptos.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    });`

It seems to have the same functionality and it also limits the zoom.

Comment: Hi @nipro. No luck. True is I need to move on and can't waste more time on this. Firefox won the infamous msg: "Your browser is not compatible con this site. Get a new one without bugs". Thanks for your time and help.-